# jqGrid add buttons for add/edit/delete in toolbar not working

Tags: jqgrid

I have tried to implement the code for adding buttons in jqGrid toolbar from the example site http://www.guriddo.net/demo/bootstrap/ but I'm surprised to find that it isn't working for me. Searched for a couple of hours but I can't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var gridDataUrl = '@Url.Action("JsonCategories", "AdminNomCategory")'

    var grid = $("#reportsGrid").jqGrid({
        url: gridDataUrl,
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: [
            '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryGuid)',
            '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryName)',
            '@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryDescription)'
        ],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'CategoryGuid', index: 'CategoryGuid', width: 10, align: 'left', classes: "nts-grid-cell", hidden: true },
            { name: 'CategoryName', index: 'CategoryName', width: 10, align: 'left', classes: "nts-grid-cell" },
            { name: 'CategoryDescription', index: 'CategoryDescription', width: 10, align: 'left', classes: "nts-grid-cell" }
        ],
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        height: 450,
        width: 1140,
        pager: '#pager',    /*jQuery('#pager'),*/
        sortname: 'CategoryGuid',
        toolbarfilter: true,

        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        caption: "Categories",

        ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
            var gsr = jQuery("#reportsGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            if (gsr) {
                var CategoryGuid = grid.jqGrid('getCell', gsr, 'CategoryGuid');
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Edit", "AdminNomCategory")/' + CategoryGuid
            }
            else {
                alert("Please select Row");
            }
        },

        @*onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
            var gsr = jQuery("#reportsGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            if (gsr) {
                var CategoryGuid = grid.jqGrid('getCell', gsr, 'CategoryGuid');
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Edit", "AdminNomCategory")/' + CategoryGuid
            }
            else {
                alert("Please select Row");
            }
        }*@
    });

    //jQuery("#reportsGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true });

    var template = "<div style='margin-left:15px;'><div> Customer ID <sup>*</sup>:</div><div> {CustomerID} </div>";
    template += "<div> Company Name: </div><div>{CompanyName} </div>";
    template += "<div> Phone: </div><div>{Phone} </div>";
    template += "<div> Postal Code: </div><div>{PostalCode} </div>";
    template += "<div> City:</div><div> {City} </div>";
    template += "<hr style='width:100%;'/>";
    template += "<div> {sData} {cData}  </div></div>";



      $('#reportsGrid').navGrid('#pager',
    // the buttons to appear on the toolbar of the grid
    { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: false, view: false, position: "left", cloneToTop: false },
    //// options for the Edit Dialog
{
    editCaption: "The Edit Dialog",
    template: template,
    errorTextFormat: function (data) {
        return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
    }
},
// options for the Add Dialog
{
    template: template,
    errorTextFormat: function (data) {
        return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
    }
},
// options for the Delete Dailog
{
    errorTextFormat: function (data) {
        return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
    }
}
    );

        grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOnEnter: true, enableClear: false });
        jQuery("#pager .ui-pg-selbox").closest("td").before("<td dir='ltr'>Rows per page </td>");
        grid.jqGrid('setGridHeight', $(window).innerHeight() - 450);
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('#reportsGrid').jqGrid('setGridHeight', $(window).innerHeight() - 450);

    });

</script>
```

I am using jqGrid 4.4.4 and ASP.NET. The thing I noticed, is that on the example page, the buttons are located inside a div with an id like 'jqGridPagerLeft', but on my page, that div has no id. So I went looking inside the jqGrid source but I'm lost and I can't figure out why it doesn't have an id allocated.

Any clues? I just want to add the buttons to the bottom toolbar. Thx!

Comment: The version 4.4.4 is **retro version** of jqGrid. It's dead and should be not more used. Starting with the end of 2014 the licence agreement of jqGrid and the name of the product were changed (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)). The new product Guriddo jqGrid JS have open source, but it's commercial (see [the prices](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). At the time I started **alternative fork** [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), provided for free under old MIT/GPL. Both forks have implemented many new features. You should choose the fork and use it.

Comment: You are welcome! You can try free jqGrid using direct URLs from CDNs described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) or to use NuGet package [free-jqgrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/4.13.0) instead of [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.jqGrid/). You can use [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid) or [bower](http://bower.io/search/?q=free-jqgrid) package alternatively (if you develop for new ASP.NET MVC Core).